# Video editing tools used in Willow Garage videos

Tags: ros, video

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

With what tools did the WG folks make those nice PR2 demo videos? The videos are simple, yet slick, and we'd like to find the shortest path to similarly simple-but-slick videos for our robot.

Thanks,

Rick Armstrong

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140396/video-editing-tools-used-in-willow-garage-videos/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2014-03-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think they used Final Cut Pro and paid a professional to edit the PR2 videos.

Not really any magic there; just good software and hard work.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-03-15**:
Ah, I think "paid" is the operative word. No wonder they look good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Joyoshare Media Cutter you may try. It's an easy-to-use and all-around video editor that works well with various media files. I have been using it for audio and video editing.

---

Originally posted by [Catherine18](https://answers.ros.org/users/58951/catherine18/) with karma: 11 on 2020-09-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1